# How can I answer my own recommendation?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

As all SE sites, Software Recommendations encourage people to share knowledge in the way of selfanswering questions, which is nice and all, but... how do I objectively answer my own question? I mean, I'm the one that puts the constrains for the recommendations, how can I answer myself without being biased?

Some of our already selfanswered questions:

- [Where I can find a desktop manager for Blackberries?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/where-i-can-find-a-desktop-manager-for-blackberries/1024#1024)
- [Make my computer screen's tint warmer at night?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/383/226)
- [Tool to remember clipboard content](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/139/226)
- [Software that can calculate PI to at least a thousand digits](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/782/226)

[Source query](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/70962/top-self-answered-questions), this is another query where the OP has [an answer on the same question.](http://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/170345/top-self-answered-questions)