# How to spot shilling posts?

Tags: discussion

What are the criteria separating veiled advertisement from honest software recommendations? How should one approach posters who answer their own questions?

(Note: this is not a dupe of [How can I answer my own recommendation](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/how-can-i-answer-my-own-recommendation))

I have read the relevant MSE questions:

- [How do I mention my own products in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers/15795#15795)
- [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)
- [Defining the limits of self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion)

...and the FAQ: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: Closely related, but not exactly duplicates: [Should we be transparent when recommending our own software?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/153), [What are the rules for self-answering your question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/131), and more generally [How are we going to moderate answers?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/305)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotting a single shilling post is next to impossible unless it is just a crap answer. Of course if it is a crap answer there are various responses depending on *how* it sucks. If a little bit of care is taken by the potential shiller though it will be an ok answer.

Honestly I have to say I'm not very worried about shilling posts because:

- This site is specifically for recommendations for products (commercial or otherwise)
- The developer(s) *should* know their own product better than someone else and to some degree the field that it is in.
- If it is a crap answer for other reasons it will be removed pretty quickly
- If it is a *good* answer other than that the user has an **undisclosed** relationship to the product that is ethically questionable but does not actually harm the site.

Really the only case that it harms the site beyond being a bit more moderation (which so far I haven't seen any serious amount of), is mediocre answers that are posted to every question that isn't a great match to the question. So in the case of one mediocre answer just comment/suggest edits to improve it and unless you think there is evidence of shilling leave it at that.

A ***pattern*** of posting of similar mediocre answers to questions from one user consistently recommending one product (or company's products) is the only type of shilling that I actually care about really. That is of course only spot-able if you are monitoring the site or you check user history occasionally when you have a post that just raises flags for you for no discernible reason.

So in conclusion, the signs that a post is shilling are mainly:

- Less than perfect match to the question requirements.
- Link-only (but then just flag NAA because that needs very little reviewer time to deal with).
- Close to verbatim copying of advertising information (but then just flag VLQ).
- A pattern of the above.
- *A pattern of linking to one product/site/company*.